# java.sql.SQLexception: no value specified for parameter 1

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I developed employee payroll management using java and MySQL.

My problem is that when I update the gender then this error occurs.

> java.sql.SQLexception: no value specified for parameter 1.

So what do I do?

Here is my code for update button:

```
 String value4 = txt_id.getText();
    int x = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure you want to update?","Update Record",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION); 
if(x==0){       
     try{
         String value1 = txt_firstname.getText();
     String value2 = txt_surname.getText();

     String value3 = txt_dob.getText();  
     String value5 = txt_email.getText(); 
     String value6 = txt_tel.getText(); 
     String value7 = txt_address.getText();
     String value8 = txt_dep.getText(); 
     String value9 = txt_add2.getText(); 
     String value10 = txt_apt.getText(); 
     String value11 = txt_pc.getText(); 
     String value12 = txt_design.getText();
     String value13 = txt_status.getText(); 
     String value14 = txt_salary.getText(); 
     String value15 = txt_job.getText(); 
     String value16 = txt_doj.getText(); 
     String sql= "update Staff_information set id='"
             +value4+"',first_name='"
             +value1+"', surname='"
             +value2+"', " + "Dob='"
             +value3+"',Email='"
             +value5+"',Telephone='"
             +value6+"'," + "Address='"
             +value7+"',Department='"
             +value8+"', Address2 = '"
             +value9+"', " + "Apartment = '"
             +value10+"', Post_code ='"
             +value11+"', " + "Designation ='"
             +value12+"', Status ='"
             +value13+"', Salary ='"
             +value14+"', job_title ='"
             +value15+"', Date_Hired ='"
             +value16+"',Gender='"+gender+"', Image=? where id='"+value4+"' ";
     pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
     pst.execute(); 
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record Updated");
     }catch(Exception e)
     { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
     }
     try{

         File file = new File(filename);
         FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
         byte[] image = new byte[(int) file.length()]; 
         fis.read(image); 

         String sql = "update Staff_information SET Image =? where id ='"+value4+"'";
         pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql); 
         pst.setBytes(1, image); 
         pst.executeUpdate(); 
         pst.close(); 

     }catch(Exception e){
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
     }

     finally { 
         try{ rs.close(); 
         pst.close(); 
         } catch(Exception e){
         }
     }

}
```

Comment: BTW you should use the prepared statement features on all your parameters, not just the image.

Comment: plz check that my 1st line is true or false????

Comment: From "What topics can I ask about here?": "Questions seeking debugging help (...) must include (...) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it (..).

Comment: _"I get this error, what do I do"_ usually doesn't make a good question on SO and understandably does not generate much qualified help. If you want to significantly improve your chances you should at least show that you tried to read the doc for that error to understand what it means and then explain why it didn't help or what is unclear. And of course if you could include a runnable example to reproduce the problem as already suggested it would help much more.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, you should use parameters for all values you want to to add in the query. Do not concatenate values into a query string.

Comment: print the value of gender to check whether its getting displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set parameter for your first sql.

```
String sql= "update Staff_information set id='"
             +value4+"',first_name='"
             +value1+"', surname='"
             +value2+"', " + "Dob='"
             +value3+"',Email='"
             +value5+"',Telephone='"
             +value6+"'," + "Address='"
             +value7+"',Department='"
             +value8+"', Address2 = '"
             +value9+"', " + "Apartment = '"
             +value10+"', Post_code ='"
             +value11+"', " + "Designation ='"
             +value12+"', Status ='"
             +value13+"', Salary ='"
             +value14+"', job_title ='"
             +value15+"', Date_Hired ='"
             +value16+"',Gender='"+gender+"', Image=? where id='"+value4+"' ";
     pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setBytes(1, somevaluehere);** 

     pst.execute();
```

Comment: No i dnt understand..can u explain it..

Comment: You are passing Image=? in first sql statement and it is expecting some parameter which needs to be set. So you need to add pst.setBytes(1, somevaluehere); where value can be some image or anything else which your program is expecting

Comment: I think in 7 line something is missing..but i dnt know what????

Comment: see line denoted by ** in my answer. You are missing parameter to a prepared statement

Comment: Ok thankss..my prblm is solved...